# Spring security and shared sessions across two services

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

I have an auth-service (which does LDAP authentication and DB authorization). - uses spring security and spring session redis
Have a data-service which uses the auth-service for authentication/session management. - uses spring session redis and spring security(uses custom auth provider to call the auth-service via a Feign client)

So when use logs-in it hits the auth-service /user endpoint and gets the sessionid back. When I use the same sessionid for an endpoint in data-service, I get the below error

Uncaught exception thrown
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot deserialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to deserialize payload. Is the byte array a result of corresponding serialization for DefaultDeserializer?; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to deserialize object type; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: XXX (an entity in auth-service)

Redis details

`127.0.0.1:6379> KEYS *
1) "spring:session:sessions:expires:ff3705e1-7403-48dc-a026-4b71d4c847f1"
2) "spring:session:index:org.springframework.session.FindByIndexNameSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_INDEX_NAME:xxxx"
3) "spring:session:sessions:ff3705e1-7403-48dc-a026-4b71d4c847f1"
4) "spring:session:expirations:1535652420000"
127.0.0.1:6379>`

Thanks